# How to understand this kind of loop?

Tags: java, while-loop

From an article on this site:
[How to read pdf file and write it to outputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891792/how-to-read-pdf-file-and-write-it-to-outputstream)

There is a loop:

```
while ((c = is.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) > 0) {
    os.write(buf, 0, c);
    os.flush();
}
```

Can someone help me understand how the while statement work here? Usually I would understand how while

```
(x < 10) {
  x ++;
  ......
}
```

But here how can can the result of `(c = is.read(buf, 0, buf.length)` larger than 0?

Also, is there a way to debug the loop to see what the value of c is in each step?

Answer (score 1):

```
while ((c = is.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) > 0) {
```

is executed in the order

assignment first : `c = is.read(buf, 0, buf.length)`

comparison second: `c > 0`

Comment: Right-o.  Order of precedence is important here.  Because there are parenthesis around the `read()` statement and the assignment to `c`, those are executed first.  Then the comparison gets executed.

Answer (score 1):

As the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26) states

> At run time, the result of the assignment expression is the value of
> the variable after the assignment has occurred. The result of an
> assignment expression is not itself a variable.

So an assignment expression like

```
c = is.read(buf, 0, buf.length)
```

regardless of where it appears in (valid) code, has a value, which can then be compared with a `<`.

> Also, is there a way to debug the loop to see what the value of c is in each step?

Either add a log statement within the loop or put a breakpoint somewhere inside the loop and check the variable table.

Answer (score 0):

It relies on the side effect of the assignment being the value assigned, it is a common idiomatic way of writing

```
int c = is.read(buf, 0, buf.length);
while (c > 0) {
    os.write(buf, 0, c);
    os.flush();
    c = is.read(buf, 0, buf.length)
}
```

Also, for improved performance, you might want to not call `os.flush()` on every loop evalutation

```
while ((c = is.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) > 0) {
    os.write(buf, 0, c);
}
os.flush();
```