# fill specific fields in excel from tables in pdf

Tags: java, c, excel

What is the quickest way ti do the following:

I have a pdf with large amount of tables. I want to filter tables with specific headings. These filtered tables have the same headings and column format. Now i want to generate a combined table in excel by adding additional columns for different tables. 
This table in should only populate specific fields from table in excel and ignore the rest.

[image]
[image]

From the above 2 tables in pdf, only the following fields should get populated in excel
[image]

Now i want to see only the rows which have different values in columns imported from different pdf tables ( ie. Show if (Field no x from any table  in pdf != Field x from any table )

(the ones in green are different (1st field under "labels" in column 1 is different from 1st field under "labels" in column 2). This should happen for all tables in pdf
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Apache POI to read the excel and have a util method in java to create pdf or do any logic as required.

https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html

Comment: I want to do the opposite. (i.e. read from PDF, do some logic, then write in excel.

Comment: sure, refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891792/how-to-read-pdf-file-and-write-it-to-outputstream  and later you can use POI to write to excel.
PDFbox is good option to read pdf and POI for excel