# Can scanner in Java read pdf files? Reading with streams

Tags: java, pdf, java.util.scanner

I would like to know if scanner in Java is able to read pdf files? If yes, how?

This is what I have, but it ain't working:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(mypdffile);
String Result = "";
while(scan.hasNext()) {
    Result += scan.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running this code?

Comment: @Goion yes I have, it doesn't work.

Comment: Then it answers your question, "If yes". From Scanner javadoc: ***"A simple text scanner which can parse primitive types and strings using regular expressions."***

Comment: [How to read pdf file and write it to outputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891792/how-to-read-pdf-file-and-write-it-to-outputstream)

Comment: No, `Scanner` is for text, and PDF is not text, or rather not text alone, lots of other stuff in there.

Comment: @Goion Thanks for your help. I used streams.

Comment: @user207421 Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using streams to read from the pdf files, as I was looking for an approach without using PdfBox,etc.

dos is my dataoutputstream

```
     try
    {
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(mypdffile);


        int read=0;
        byte[] buf=new byte[1024];

        //read in file 
        while((read=fis.read(buf))>0) {

            dos.write(buffer,0,read);
                    dos.flush();

        }
    dos.close();



    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Comment: This will not work. The line `result+=new String(buf);` will harm your PDF, you will end up with different bytes than you had before, due to encoding. PDF is a binary file format.

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr , how would you suggest converting the bytes to string?

Comment: If you want the text (mark, copy and paste in Adobe), then use PDFBox text extraction. You won't be able to do this without a library. If you just want to copy the (binary) bytes, then write to a ByteArrayOutputStream and then call  toByteArray().

Comment: Yeah that is much better.

Answer (score 1):

No `Scanner` will not work as you intend with PDF files. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784825/how-to-read-pdf-files-using-java) for suggestions on how to read PDFs in Java. The TL;DR is that you probably want to use a library.

Comment: Thanks, so is there any other way other than PdfBox , like would buffered reader work?

Comment: @Candyfloss BufferedReader surely won't help you. Readers are for character based formats, but PDF is binary. You need InputStreams, not readers. But we really do not know the inners of PDF file format to help you.

Comment: @kingkupps Thanks, I didn't wanna use pdfbox,etc so I ended up using streams.